# How to disable 'only origins'

Tags: transforms, object-mode

So, I'm using the latest build of Blender 2.81 (November 15 2019) on Mac. There is this nifty new feature that allows origins to be manipulated freely without affecting the actually object's transform data. This is quite cool.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to find the toggle for it? Somehow I accidentally enabled it in my file, and cannot disable it. This is rather not ideal for animating objects.

How do I disable the "only origins" toggle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Options* can be found in the *Tool Settings* header on the right-hand side. If you cannot see the *Tool Settings*, right click in the area where the *View*, *Select*, *Add* and *Object* menus can be found and activate *Header > Show Tool Settings*.

[image: Options]

[image: Show Tool Settings]

Comment: Thank you very much! All the images I had seen of its location must have been from an older build or something (it showed it under the pivot point selection menu).